# Laravel 6 database connection error. Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6

Couldn't connect to the database with `laravel 6.0`
SQL user and password were working fine and running smoothly on other project but the same credentials are not working on `laravel 6`.
I have created another user and give it all permissions but still got the same error.
I had cleared all kind of laravel cache,
remove the bootstrap and storage cache but nothing happened.
Please help me to solve this problem.

> OS version: ubuntu 18.04
>   Server: nginx
>   Database: mysql 5.7.28
>   PHP: 7.2

[image: my config/database.php]

Comment: include the `error` info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sharp(#) character recognizes as comment in .env file.

So you should **put your password in double quotes**("")

like this:

```
DB_PASSWORD="xfs#sds"
```